# How to add an article to a page automatically

Tags: views, nodes

What I want to do is to add the title and the body of an article I create on my homepage just as you would do it for a news.
I've been trying to make this work but I can't find a way to do it without having to remember the path and then manually creating a block.

Comment: Please have a look at the Views module. It's in core since Drupal 8. Create a new view, add block display to it listing articles by your desired logic and when you are done go to Drupal's regions/block page and choose the block there to place it in the desired region and adjust its visibility settings to only by shown on the front page. Done.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways to do this based on your requirements.

1. Display multiple articles on your homepage

As @leymanxx mentioned create a view with a page display then set the path of the page you created as your default front page.

2. Display a single article on the homepage

Create an article and set that's article path as your default front page.

You can read more [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/265172)